# Find equal columns in data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frame objects 'x' and 'ans1', there are 500 columns in 'x' and 7 in 'ans1'
How can I find names of columns from 'x', which are equal to columns from 'ans1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `%in%`:

```
names(x) %in% names(ans1)
```

See `?match` for more detail.

Comment: you can use intersect (which is a wrapper on match)

Comment: @David, unfortunately, your modification of this solution doesn't consider the oder of the values in the columns. If order is important, please reconsider using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to use `identical()` with the `digest` package:

```
library(digest)

x <- data.frame(aa = c("s", "d", "f"), bb = 1:3)
ans1 <- data.frame(bb = c("d", "s", "z"), cc = 1:3)

(myMatches<-lapply(x, function(myX) sapply(ans1,
  function(y) identical(digest(y), digest(myX))))
)

# $aa
#    bb    cc 
# FALSE FALSE 

# $bb
#    bb    cc 
# FALSE  TRUE
```

This indicates that the data in the column `bb` in the data.frame `x` is equal to the data in column `cc` in data.frame `ans1`.

To obtain the matches only,

```
unlist(lapply(myMatches, function(x) which(x)))
# bb.cc 
# 2
```

Again, the data in column `bb` from `x` are identical to the data in column `cc` in `ans1`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
mtcarsSub <- mtcars[c(1,4,7)]
names(mtcarsSub) <- letters[1:3]
matches <- sapply(mtcarsSub,function(x) sapply(mtcars,identical,x))
matches
         a     b     c
mpg   TRUE FALSE FALSE
cyl  FALSE FALSE FALSE
disp FALSE FALSE FALSE
hp   FALSE  TRUE FALSE
drat FALSE FALSE FALSE
wt   FALSE FALSE FALSE
qsec FALSE FALSE  TRUE
vs   FALSE FALSE FALSE
am   FALSE FALSE FALSE
gear FALSE FALSE FALSE
carb FALSE FALSE FALSE

names(mtcars)[apply(matches,2,which)]
[1] "mpg"  "hp"   "qsec"
```