# Find columns with same data in one data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 1 data.frame named A, there are 5000 columns in it. How can I find columns in this data.frame that are equal to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @John mentioned, there are problems with using `duplicated`. I would add that transposing the data.frame forces all the data into a same data type before it is even compared with `duplicated`. On an example, here is a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame( a = LETTERS[1:3],
                  b = 1:3,
                  c = as.character(1:3),
                  d = LETTERS[1:3],
                  e = 1:3,
                  f = 1:3)
df
#   a b c d e f
# 1 A 1 1 A 1 1
# 2 B 2 2 B 2 2
# 3 C 3 3 C 3 3
```

Note that column `c` is very similar to columns `b`, `e`, and `f`, but not identical because of the different types (character versus numeric). The solution suggested by @Jubbles would disregard these differences.

Instead, it seems more appropriate to use the `identical` function on the columns of your data.frame. You can compare columns two-by-two using `outer`:

```
are.cols.identical <- function(col1, col2) identical(df[,col1], df[,col2])
identical.mat      <- outer(colnames(df), colnames(df),
                            FUN = Vectorize(are.cols.identical))
identical.mat
# [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

From here, you can use clustering to identify groups of identical columns (there may be better ways so if you know one, feel free to comment or even edit my answer.)

```
library(cluster)
distances <- as.dist(!identical.mat)
tree      <- hclust(distances)
cut       <- cutree(tree, h = 0.5)
cut
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 2

split(colnames(df), cut)
# $`1`
# [1] "a" "d"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "b" "e" "f"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "c"
```

**Edit 1:** to disregard differences in floating point values, one can use

```
are.cols.identical <- function(col1,col2) isTRUE(all.equal((df[,col1],df[,col2]))
```

**Edit 2:** a more efficient method than clustering for grouping the names of identical columns is

```
cut <- apply(identical.mat, 1, function(x)match(TRUE, x))
split(colnames(df), cut)
```

Comment: Upvote from me.  Thanks for providing a more exhaustive answer than mine.

Comment: I like the use of cluster here.  There is room for even more potential answers here as this one doesn't address the issue of differences in floating point values that arise even though the values are fundamentally identical.

Comment: An alternative way to extract information from identical.mat might be... `which(identical.mat, arr.ind = TRUE)` (only using the lower.tri() would make that better)

Comment: Thank you @John. `which` is a good one if the user wants to show every pair of duplicated data. Also, differences in floating point can be addressed (i.e. ignored) if `identical()` above is replaced with `isTRUE(all.equal())`.

Answer (score 6):

This question is very similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10106163/1281189), with subtle differences yet with the same caveats.

I would again suggest using `digest()`, as in the following (thanks to @flodel for the data.frame and for a very nice suggestion above)

```
df <- data.frame( a = LETTERS[1:3],
  b = 1:3,
  c = as.character(1:3),
  d = LETTERS[1:3],
  e = 1:3,
  f = 1:3)

dfDig <- sapply(df, digest)

ansL <- lapply(seq_along(dfDig), function(x) names(which(dfDig == dfDig[x])))

unique(ansL)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "d"

# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "e" "f"

# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

This still won't distinguish between `1.0` and `1`, though.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments by @flodel, the following can be used alternatively after creating `dfDig`

```
split(colnames(df), vapply(dfDig, match, 1L, dfDig))
```

Comment: +1 - Nice, very concise. I did not know about `digest`, thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Using `match` may be faster than `which`. This seems to work: `split(colnames(df), vapply(dfDig, match, 1L, dfDig))`

Comment: @flodel, that's a great suggestion. I'll add it above.

Answer (score 2):

How about transposing the dataframe and using `duplicated()`?

```
B <- as.data.frame(t(A))
dup1 <- duplicated(B)
# if you want to identify all duplicated rows
dup2 <- duplicated(B, fromLast = TRUE)
dup_final <- dup1 * dup2
saved_colnames <- colnames(A)[dup_final]
```

Comment: @David Kakauridze: I think the last line I added should take care of that.

Comment: The duplicated() command will treat each value as text.  Certain values may be considered equal in some situations but not be as text (or even in their natural form).  For example, many values that are 0 will not be represented as such, (e.g. tan(pi)).  Floating point numbers could be a serious problem here.  It might be fine for the questioners situation but future readers should be warned that this is not a general solution. (and there isn't a general solution without a more complex function)

Comment: @John: Thank you for the caveats.  My proposed answer is admittedly "quick-and-dirty" and, as you pointed out, ripe for exceptional cases.